How do I set the timeout parameter in dask scheduler
I was trying to run dask-distributed to distribute some big computation in a slurm cluster.
I was always getting a "TimeoutError: No valid workers found" message (this came from line 6130 in distributed/scheduler.py)
I have no idea how to change that Timeout parameter. I have tried in the cfg file with

jobqueue.slurm.connect-timeout
jobqueue.slurm.tcp-timeout
jobqueue.slurm.no-workers-timeout
jobqueue.slurm.death-timeout
jobqueue.slurm.timeout

But none of these worked. I finally had to manually modify the code to make that timeout parameter be big enough to make the scheduler wait enough to get at least one job running (the fact that the whole job raises an exception in such a short time sounds bonkers to me, but that is a different issue).
So what is the config parameter to set this variable correctly in a yaml file? I have not been able to find this info in the documentation

Hi, could you share the code of how you are launching Workers and tasks? Maybe your workers take too much time to start?

Thanks for your answer: Yes, the workers take too much time to start. That is why I get that error. What I want is to be able to modify with the yaml config file the timeout parameter in line 6318 of this file:
https://github.com/dask/distributed/blob/main/distributed/scheduler.py
Because it is set too low and I cannot (for the life of me) find out how to set that timeout parameter (other than manually hardcoding it).

If you refer to this line, from inside the scatter function, there are several things to try:

Increase the timeout that is a kwarg o the function,
But I think it would be better to use client.wait_for_worker, to get at least one worker before trygin to scatter.

